# What database to choose from?

Tags: mongodb, firebase, realm

Realm Database or MySQL or MongoDB or the standard Firebase.

I am curious why would anyone choose one over another. I am in a group project and one of the members in the group suggested that we should use Realm Database over Firebase. He tried to explain to me the reason but I was not able to comprehend.

What has your experience been like? Is one database more user-friendly over another? 
Firebase seems to have very nice documentation.

Which one would you guys suggest?

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are three different things.

Realm is a database for storing content locally on a device.

MySQL is usually used together with a web server. If you have a server and need to store data, you can use MySQL.

Firebase is Google's alternative for building your own server. It gives you tools that allow you to avoid having to build your own web server, such as Firestore, which lets you do CRUD operations directly from devices without needing to send that information through a server first.

Answer (score 1):

If you works on small project you must going with MYSQL database. Its very simple and easy to understand. But if your project are big like that organisation type projects I recommend you to going with MongoDB.